# How do I convert a @Html.ActionLink() to a checkbox list?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

I have existing code that links different categories to events and when you click on a category, it displays all the events with those categories. I want to convert it to a checklist where the checked boxes/ categories can be used to display events of multiple categories in one go, much like a filter. How do I convert my @Html.ActionLink() to @Html.Checkbox when I only have ID and no boolean value? Can I create hidden boolean variables that can help me? I'm new to C# and Asp.net so any input is appreciated.

Comment: You can pass in a boolean literal.  The checked property is the value being tracked.  ex.  `@Html.CheckBox("Liquids", false)`

Comment: What do I do if I don't have a bool value in my model? Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Are you referring to the post-back model?  Create a new class that has the all of the fields you wish to post back.  I will attempt to write up an answer that explains the workflow.

Comment: @hijinxbassist So I think it is a post-back model, I need a way to get connect the bool value of checked/unchecked box to my data and then return my events based on what all categories are checked when the submit button is clicked. i was suggested to use jquery, will that help me connect the data?

Comment: It is unclear what the end goal is here.  The question above sounds like you want to post the categories (and possibly other data) back to the controller.  If you are looking to use those value in the frontend instead using javascript, I suggest reading through resources related to frontend coding.  I would also recommend jquery, as it is easy to get started and a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Html.CheckBox` control, you do not need to pass in a variable for your boolean, you can pass in the literal value.  The boolean value you use will set the checkbox checked property to the value of your boolean.

```
@Html.CheckBox("Liquids", false)
```

The above results in a new checkbox named "Liquids" that is unchecked.

When you post the values back to the controller, each value needs to be bound to a parameter in the method signature.  You can use a bool param, or use some sort of data model.

By param

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CategoryPost(bool Liquids)
```

By model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CategoryPost(CategoryData data)
```

model

```
public class CategoryData
{
    public bool Liquids { get; set; }
    public bool Gases { get; set; }
    ... etc
}
```

The important part here is that the name of the checkbox matches the name of the binding param.

If you need to nest a data structure inside of another, use "dot notation" to resolve the name.  eg.  `name="ParentData.Liquids"`.